# Склонировать целую группу репозиториев GitLab

Tags: gitlab, git-clone

Есть большая-пребольшая группа GitLab-репозиториев из сплошных микросервисов, мать их. Мне нужно их все загрузить себе на локальный компьютер. Хотелось бы это сделать, не напрягаясь чрезмерно. Подскажите какое-нибудь решение.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29099456/5000805

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть у меня относительно простой способ получить проекты группы через GitLab API. Шаги ниже.

1. Откройте в браузере, где вы залогинены, ссылку вида
   [https://`gitlab.com`/api/v4/groups/`9970`/projects?per_page=100](https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/9970/projects?per_page=100)
2. Выделенные части в адресе замените на ваши данные, идентификатор группы можно найти на её основной странице
   [image: где найти требуемый id]
3. Сохраните (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) данные по ссылке в файл projects.json
4. В терминале выполните команду
   `jq -r '.[].ssh_url_to_repo' < /path/to/projects.json | xargs -n1 git clone`
5. Помимо самого Git потребуются findutils и [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/), последняя из утилит обычно не входит в базовую поставку — её придётся установить дополнительно.
6. Если репозиториев больше сотни, то придётся вручную перейти ко второй странице, добавив query-параметр `&page=2` в конец ссылки, и продолжить скачивание.

Увы, есть ограничение. Метод не работает с вложенными группами, выкачиваются проекты только на самом верхнем уровне.

Comment: Лол, это работает) Правда id группы у меня не показывало, пришлось в исходниках страницы смотреть https://i.stack.imgur.com/eghUx.png